# How do I Associating a Label to RadioButtonList control so it is 508 compliant?

Tags: radiobuttonlist, section508

I have tried several methods to get this control to pass 508 compliance testing, but they all seem to fail. I do not get feedback from the tester’s, only pass/fail.
I suspect is has to do with the table that is automatically rendered around the Radio Buttons. I suspect that the labels must be inside the table, which is not an option with a RadioButtonList. Here are the methods that I have tried and failed.

Fieldset/legend Solution

ASP/NET Page:

```html
<fieldset>
<legend>Review By:</legend>
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="FilterType" AutoPostBack="true" Width="100%"
       BorderWidth="1"   OnSelectedIndexChanged="FilterType_OnSelectedIndexChanged" />
</fieldset>
```

Rendered HTML:

```html
<fieldset>
<legend>Review By:</legend>
<table id="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType" border="0" style="border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;width:100%;">
        <tr>
<td><input id="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_0" type="radio"
name="ctl00$contentBody$FilterType" value="1" 
onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$contentBody$FilterType$0
\',\'\')',  0)" /><label for="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_0">Attending MD</label>
</td>
        </tr><tr>
<td><input id="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_1" type="radio"
name="ctl00$contentBody$FilterType" value="2" 
onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$contentBody$FilterType$1
\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_1">CERMe Review 
Types</label></td>
        </tr><tr>
<td><input id="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_2" type="radio" 
name="ctl00$contentBody$FilterType" value="3" 
onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$contentBody$FilterType$2
\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_2">Treating 
Specialty</label></td>
        </tr><tr>
<td><input id="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_3" type="radio" 
name="ctl00$contentBody$FilterType" value="4" 
onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$contentBody$FilterType$3
\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_3">Ward Location</label>
</td>
        </tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
```

Using an AssociatedControlID  to link the control to label

ASP.Net Page:

```html
<asp:Label ID="lblHiddenReviewType"  AssociatedControlID="FilterType" runat="server">
<div>Review Type:</div></asp:Label> 
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="FilterType" AutoPostBack="true" Width="100%"
BorderWidth="1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="FilterType_OnSelectedIndexChanged" />
```

Rendered HTML:

```html
<td>
            <label for="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType"  
id="ctl00_contentBody_lblHiddenReviewType"><div>Review Type:</div></label> 
                <table id="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType" border="0" style="border-
width:1px;border-style:solid;width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td><input id="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_0" 
type="radio" name="ctl00$contentBody$FilterType" value="1" 
onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$contentBody$FilterType$0
\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_0">Attending MD</label></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><input id="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_1"   
type="radio" name="ctl00$contentBody$FilterType" value="2" 
onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$contentBody$FilterType$1 
\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_1">CERMe Review Type</label>
</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><input id="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_2" 
type="radio" name="ctl00$contentBody$FilterType" value="3" 
onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$contentBody$FilterType$2
\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_2">Treating 
Specialty</label></td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td><input id="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_3" 
type="radio" name="ctl00$contentBody$FilterType" value="4" 
onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$contentBody$FilterType$3
\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_3">Ward Location</label>
</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

            </td>
```

Surround the Control with its own Panel

ASP.Net Page:

```html
<asp:Panel id="pnlRadial" GroupingText="Review Type: " runat="server">
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="FilterType"  AutoPostBack="true" Width="100%"
 BorderWidth="1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="FilterType_OnSelectedIndexChanged" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Rendered HTML:

```html
<div id="ctl00_contentBody_pnlRadial">
<fieldset>
<legend>Review Type:</legend>
<table id="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType" border="0" style="border-width:1px;border-
style:solid;width:100%;">
                <tr>
<td><input id="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_0" type="radio" 
name="ctl00$contentBody$FilterType" value="1" 
onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$contentBody$FilterType$0
\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_0">Attending MD</label></td>
                </tr><tr>
<td><input id="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_1" type="radio" 
name="ctl00$contentBody$FilterType" value="2" 
onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$contentBody$FilterType$1
\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_1">Reviewer</label></td>
                </tr><tr>
<td><input id="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_2" type="radio" 
name="ctl00$contentBody$FilterType" value="4" 
onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$contentBody$FilterType$2
\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_2">Treating 
Specialty</label></td>
                </tr><tr>
<td><input id="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_3" type="radio" 
name="ctl00$contentBody$FilterType" value="5" 
onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$contentBody$FilterType$3
\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_3">Ward Location</label>
</td>
                </tr><tr>
<td><input id="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_4" type="radio" 
name="ctl00$contentBody$FilterType" value="3" 
onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$contentBody$FilterType$4
\',\'\')', 0)" /><label for="ctl00_contentBody_FilterType_4">Service Section</label>
</td>
                </tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated !!

Answer (score 0):

I would request that the tester to provide more information than pass/fail, at least what they are using to test. Maybe asking the Section 508 Coordinator to get involved may help some. Your first or second snippet should pass. A compliant solution would look like:

```
<fieldset>
 <legend>Review type</legend>
 <table role="presentation"> //bonus for the role, not required
  <tr>
   <td>
    <input id="option1" name="myGroup" type="radio" />
   </td>
   <td>
    <label for="option1">Option 1</label>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <input id="option2" name="myGroup" type="radio" />
   </td>
   <td>
    <label for="option2">Option 2</label>
   </td>
  </tr>
  ....
 </table>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer.  Here is the problem, it is an HTML solution. The ASP RadioButtonList puts the radio buttons out there in a HTML table that is not easily modified. I am seeing some other solutions where they try and modify the attributes on page load, but I am still not quite sure how to implement.

Comment: These days most screen readers can see that if a table is being used for layout or holds data. By adding `role="presentation"`, to a screen reader, the table tags are removed. See https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/aria-unofficial/raw-file/tip/index.html